# How to insert a character in a list, based on the consecutive appearance of two elements from another list? Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a lot of strings and a function that inserts a character in a string, according to a condition. The problem is that my code somehow sees the input string `s` wrongly.

The list `s` consists of elements from two lists: (1) member list (2) non-member list. My goal is to insert the number '1' into `s` when any 'member' is followed by any two consequtive 'non-members'. A maximum of one '1' should be added to `s`. This is the code.

```
import pandas as pd
members = ['AA', 'BBB', 'CC', 'DDDD']
non_members = ['EEEE', 'FF', 'GGG', 'HHHHH', 'III', 'JJ']
s = ['AA', 'EEEE', 'GGG', 'FF']
```

So the result I am trying to achieve for s is to get the following output:

```
['AA', '1', 'EEEE', 'GGG', 'FF']
```

This is my code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns =['string'])
d = df['string']

def func(row):
    out = ""
    look = 2
    for i in range(len(row)-look):
        out += row[i]
        if (row[i] in members) & \
           (row[i+1] in non_members) & \
           (row[i+2] in non_members):
            out += '1' + row[i+1:]
            break
    return out

e = d.apply(func)
print(e)
```

This gives the following result:

```
0      
1    EE
2     G
3
```

But what I hope to get is this:

```
['AA', '1', 'EEEE', 'GGG', 'FF']
```

Any suggestions how to solve this?

This question is related to this one: [How to add a character to a list if two items from another list appear consecutively? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493964/how-to-add-a-character-to-a-list-if-two-items-from-another-list-appear-consecuti)

Comment: The problem in your idea is that `row[i], row[i+1], ...`  do not behave like you expect, try to `print` them you will see that you don't access the next row but more the characters of your string

Comment: Yes, thank you I did notice that. But cannot figure out how to insert the '1' between the items on the lists, instead of inside the items on the list.

Answer (score 1):

You can use shift to figure out where that condition is met.

```
mask = ((df['string'].isin(members)) 
         & (df['string'].shift(-1).isin(non_members)) 
         & (df['string'].shift(-2).isin(non_members)))
```

One way to insert in the rows in between might be to do something like this.

```
import numpy as np
df.set_index(df.index*2, inplace=True)

indices = mask[mask==True].index.values+1

df_add = pd.DataFrame(data=np.repeat(1, len(indices)), index=indices, columns=['string'])

pd.concat([df, df_add]).sort_index()
  string
0     AA
1      1
2   EEEE
4    GGG
6     FF
```

Comment: I like the way of multiplying the index by 2 and adding the row the way you did. I was writing an answer with `concat`, but the main idea is the `mask` so good job :)

Comment: The 'row' is used because in reality `s` is a DataFrame with many lists `s`, with each row in the DataFrame containing a list. So, is it possible to get the result as one list, rather than splitting the list into rows? So that the result becomes this: `['AA', '1', 'EEEE', 'GGG', 'FF']` ?

Comment: @twhale I think this answer reply to the question the way you asked, your comment suggest that actually, your df is built such as `df = pd.DataFrame({'string':[s]})` where each row of the column 'string' is a list, which a different question then, am I right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I realise now that I asked the question in the wrong way! Apologies.

Comment: I will ask a new question then.

Comment: @twhale good idea to not mix up everything. Add the link of this question in your new one, and vice versa if possible.

Answer (score 0):

@ALollz code looks cleaner beacsue they use mask and isin but yeah shift is definitely the idea.

```
import pandas as pd

import sys 

def fun(row):
    members = ['AA', 'BBB', 'CC', 'DDDD']
    non_members = ['EEEE', 'FF', 'GGG', 'HHHHH', 'III', 'JJ']
    try:
        if (row["string"] in members):
            if(row["next"] in non_members):
                if(row["nextnext"] in non_members):
                    return(1)
        return(0)
    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()[0]
        print(e)
        print("!")
        return(0)
    return(0)

def insert_row(idx, df, df_insert):
    dfA = df.iloc[:idx, ]
    dfB = df.iloc[idx:, ]
    df = dfA.append(df_insert).append(dfB).reset_index(drop = True)
    return df

def primary(d):
    df = d.copy()
    a = d.shift(-1)
    b = d.shift(-2)
    df['next'] = a
    df['nextnext'] = b
    e = df.apply(fun,axis=1)
    x = 0
    while( x<len(e) and e[x]==0 ):
        x+=1
    if(x!=len(e)):
        d = insert_row(x+1,d,pd.DataFrame(["1"], columns=["string"]))
    return(d)

s = ['AA', 'EEEE', 'GGG', 'FF']

df = pd.DataFrame(s, columns =['string'])
print(primary(df))
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the answer of ALollz, but prefer a more visual approach. Here's an example that requires two inserts.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
members = ['AA', 'BBB', 'CC', 'DDDD']
non_members = ['EEEE', 'FF', 'GGG', 'HHHHH', 'III', 'JJ']
s = ['AA', 'EEEE', 'GGG', 'CC', 'III', 'JJ']
ser = pd.Series(s)
# view the multiple "frames" from the list in a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([ser, ser, ser.shift(-1), ser.shift(-2)], 
index=["orig","s", "s+1", "s+2"]).T

   orig     s   s+1  s+2
0    AA    AA  EEEE  GGG
1  EEEE  EEEE   GGG   CC
2   GGG   GGG    CC  III
3    CC    CC   III   JJ
4   III   III    JJ  NaN
5    JJ    JJ   NaN  NaN
```

Similar to the mask approach, create a column showing whether the conditions are fulfilled.

```
df["s"] = df["s"].isin(members)
df["s+1"] = df["s+1"].isin(non_members)
df["s+2"] = df["s+2"].isin(non_members)
df["fulfilled"] = df.all(axis=1)

   orig      s    s+1    s+2  fulfilled
0    AA   True   True   True       True
1  EEEE  False   True  False      False
2   GGG  False  False   True      False
3    CC   True   True   True       True
4   III  False   True  False      False
5    JJ  False  False  False      False
```

get the index of the "1" positions to be inserted into the final s_out list. This is simply the orig index plus the index in only "True" positions

```
index = df.loc[df.fulfilled].index
df.loc[index, "index in s_out"] = index + np.arange(1, len(index) + 1)

   orig      s    s+1    s+2  fulfilled  index in s_out
0    AA   True   True   True       True             1.0
1  EEEE  False   True  False      False             NaN
2   GGG  False  False   True      False             NaN
3    CC   True   True   True       True             5.0
4   III  False   True  False      False             NaN
5    JJ  False  False  False      False             NaN
```

Insert the "1" into the s_out list at the required positions.

```
s_out = s.copy()
for i in df["index in s_out"].dropna().astype(int):
    s_out.insert(i, "1")
s_out

['AA', '1', 'EEEE', 'GGG', 'CC', '1', 'III', 'JJ']
```