# How to add a character to a list if two items from another list appear consecutively? Python

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe

I have a DataFrame in which each cell contains a list. I have a function that aims to insert a '1' into each list, based on a condition. However, my code is not doing what I expect.

Each list `s` consists of elements from two other lists: (1) member list (2) non-member list. My goal is to insert the number '1' into `s` when any 'member' is followed by any two consequtive 'non-members'. A maximum of one '1' should be added to `s`. This is the code.

```
import pandas as pd

members = ['AA', 'BBB', 'CC', 'DDDD']
non_members = ['EEEE', 'FF', 'GGG', 'HHHHH', 'III', 'JJ']
s = ['AA', 'EEEE', 'GGG', 'FF']
df = pd.DataFrame({'string':[s]}) # each row of the column 'string' is a list
```

So given `s`:

```
['AA', 'EEEE', 'GGG', 'FF']
```

the result I am trying to achieve is this:

```
['AA', '1', 'EEEE', 'GGG', 'FF']
```

This is my code:

```
d = df['string']

def func(row):
    out = ""
    look = 2
    for i in range(len(row)-look):
        out += row[i]
        if (row[i] in members) & \
           (row[i+1] in non_members) & \
           (row[i+2] in non_members):
            out += '1' + row[i+1:]
            break
    return out

e = d.apply(func)
print(e)
```

This gives only the following result:

```
string    
dtype: object
```

But what I try to get is this:

```
['AA', '1', 'EEEE', 'GGG', 'FF']
```

What is the simplest way to get there?

The above question is related to this one: [How to insert a character in a list, based on the consecutive appearance of two elements from another list? Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50492022/how-to-insert-a-character-in-a-list-based-on-the-consecutive-appearance-of-two/50492579?noredirect=1#comment88000437_50492579)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with this question, your answer is to change your function `func` by:

```
def func(row):
    look = 2
    for i in range(len(row)-look):
        if (row[i] in members) & \
           (row[i+1] in non_members) & \
           (row[i+2] in non_members):
            # if the condition is met, return the list with the 1 added where you want
            return row[:i+1] + ['1'] + row[i+1:]
    # in case you never met your condition, you return the original list without changes
    return row
```

Your problem was that you mixed `str` and `list` type in your `func`

Comment: @twhale glad it works. As you said you are beginner, I would suggest you to have a look on how to use the powerful of pandas, having a list in a cell is not the best way and the answer of your related question with the mask is probably faster. Because this way work but if you reach big data set, then it might take a while :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, there are still many things I do not understand but I will work my way up through pandas as well, thanks for the tips!